# Winforms Control with custom LayoutEngine

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In C# WinForms, if a control is docked then the margin is never used. In most cases the trick would be to place the control inside a panel with some padding. Now I'm looking for a solution without the container-panel, because my control is already a descendant of panel. So for the user it would be confusing an I would have route most of the properties from the container-panel to the inner panel.

My first try was a custom [LayoutEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/ms171727.aspx) but there is not much on that topic. But it kinda works. But I've some problems with the surrounding (sibling controls) they overlap the part which I made my control "bigger" (margin). In my custom layoutengine is make the control Size bigger (adding the margin) and moving the x/y accordingly

[Image Custom Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3mnR.png)

The green control is my custom panel, which is docked bottom and has an margin of 10, the red control is a normal panel which is also docked bottom.

Now I could resize the sibling controls but I think this would make more problems? Is there any way to tell the other (sibling) controls that the size of my control has changed and that they should update their layout?

```
public class CustomLayoutEngine : LayoutEngine
{
    public override bool Layout(object container, LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs)
    {
        bool result = base.Layout(container, layoutEventArgs);

        Control parent = container as Control;

        if (parent.Dock == DockStyle.Bottom && (parent.Margin.Left > 0 || parent.Margin.Right > 0))
        {
            Int32 newWidth = parent.Size.Width - (parent.Margin.Left + parent.Margin.Right);
            Int32 newHeight = parent.Size.Height - (parent.Margin.Bottom);

            parent.Size = new Size(newWidth, parent.Size.Height);
            parent.Location = new Point(parent.Location.X + parent.Margin.Left, parent.Location.Y - parent.Margin.Bottom);
        }           

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the sizing/layout composition can be easily done via some other framework -> Have You heard about **WPF**? =) You can even combine this with winforms, You can just add WPF window and use it's specialities like Grid/stackPanel/otherPanel layouts.

Comment: I'd rather use WPF but I can't -> company/boss reasons

Comment: In that case... You can handle events for `Resize` of form/the control and make each sibling around the area to call `Refresh()` method. I believe it will invokes the `OnPaint` event or something similar of the control. However You should keep general layout - sizes between controls in LayoutObject, which will tell each object "You can use this width, this size" and also "it is time to refresh, size has changed".

Comment: Usually you can achieve the same by simply setting a Anchor (in the properties of the control). It will keep the padding and try to even resize it so the padding will be the same. Did you try that?

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RezaAghaei no it's not, I'm not the "user" of the (green) control, I'm the developer. I can tell the "user" to put a (TableLayout)Panel underneath the get the desired effect.

Comment: @Cataklysim Docking a control does use the anchors to get the doc effect. But ther is no way to get the surrounding margin. And even it would be possible, then every user of my control would have to do this everytime by hand.